# aws-amplify inbuilt way to redirect to Microsoft sign-in page in reactjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

**NOTE** : **I don't want to use inbuilt hostedUI page of AWS Cognito service**.

I have my own custom login page with which I already integrated **google** and **facebook** login by providing two more buttons called `Google Login` `Facebook Login`.

When `Google Login` button is clicked, it opens directly (from my custom login page) google sign-in page with following code,

```
const googleLogin = async () => {

    Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Google }).then(cred => {
      ...
    }).catch(e => {
      ...
    });

}
```

and same kind of implementation for `facebook` : provider: `{ provider: CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Facebook}` and it will redirect me to facebook login page.

Now, I want to integrate `Auzre-Ad login` to my login page. So added one more button `Microsoft Azure Login`

```
const microsofAzureLogin = async () => {

        Auth.federatedSignIn({ /* **What should I add here** */ }).then(cred => {
          ...
        }).catch(e => {
          ...
        });

}
```

What should I add in above code so when `Microsoft Azure Login` button is clicked, it redirects me to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the name, you have given in Cognito for Microsoft, as an OIDC provider.

Which is mentioned in [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html), under `identity_provider` param.

> Add this parameter to bypass the hosted UI and redirect your user to a provider sign-in page. The value of the identity_provider parameter is the name of the identity provider (IdP) as it appears in your user pool.

---

```
    const azureLogin = () => {
        window.location.href = `https://${process.env.COGNITO_DOMAIN}/oauth2/authorize?
        identity_provider=${process.env.IDENTITY_PROVIDER_NAME}
        &redirect_uri=${process.env.COGNITO_REDIRECT_SIGNIN}
        &response_type=CODE
        &client_id=${process.env.COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID}
        &scope=${process.env.COGNITO_SCOPE}`;
      }
```

Comment: I am trying to find a test project in ReactJS runs and SSO's an user with Azure AD that links to AWS Cognito.

For example, how do I get users to show something like a Hosted UI that they sign in to Azure AD and then Redirect them back to ReactJS to extract the token.

Its very hard to find a test project, as I did see Amazon Amplify, but nothing specific.

Does anyone have any test projects to share please..

Comment: Not sure if it's gonna help you but you can check this one : https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cognito-saml-idp @Doyyan